How to get a link to a subject in Angular?
I'm trying to write a directive that will be attached to a component and with this it will be possible to subscribe to its events. This directive should serve as a connector
@Component({
    selector: 'app-authors',
    templateUrl: './authors.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./authors.component.scss']
})
export class AuthorsComponent
    implements OnInit, OnDestroy, IEntryValidationSubject
{
    authorsForm: UntypedFormGroup;
    authorsFormArray: UntypedFormArray;
    subscriptions: Subscription = new Subscription();
    authorsDataSource: FirstLastNameDataSource<AuthorViewModel>;
     
    private _isValid: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(true);

    public $validationStatusChange: Observable<boolean> =
        this._isValid.asObservable();

    @Input() entryId: number;

    constructor(
        private fb: UntypedFormBuilder,
        public editorValidationService: EditorValidationService,
        public elementRef: ElementRef
        ...
    ) {
        this.editorValidationService.register(this, 'another');
        ...
    }
    public isValid(): boolean {
        const controls =
            this.authorsFormArray && this.authorsFormArray.controls;
        let isValid = true;
        if (controls) {
            // валидируем только заполненные поля
            isValid = controls
                .filter(control => this.isFilled(control.value))
                .every(author => author.valid);
        }
        this._isValid.next(isValid);
        return isValid;
    }

   ]
}


I need to know if form isValid or not
@Directive({
    selector: '[validateSubject]'
})
export class ValidationDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    @Input() validateSubject: IEntryValidationSubject;

    constructor(
        @Host() @Optional() private host: IEntryValidationSubject,
        private validationService: EditorValidationService
    ) {
    }

I tried to get the link via @Host() but it didn't work

please explain what you are trying to do ultimately, there is no need for a directive here! and the behaviour subject is not needed

You can do this by creating an @Input() on your directive, then passing in an instance of the component into it.
@Directive({
  selector: '[appValidation]',
  standalone: true,
})
export class ValidationDirective {
  @Input() appValidationHost: IValidatableThing;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log(this.appValidationHost);
    this.appValidationHost.validationStatus$.subscribe((isValid) => {
      alert(`Directive valid: ${isValid}`);
    });
  }
}

The use would look something like this:
<app-my-component 
   #validateMe      <--make this a template variable
   appValidation    <--this component has the directive
   [appValidationHost]="validateMe"  <--pass this component into the directive
>  
</app-my-component>

And then you can have an interface that's applied to anything that should work with the directive.
export interface IValidatableThing {
  get validationStatus$(): Observable<boolean>;
}

export class MyComponentComponent implements IValidatableThing {
  private _validationStatus = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  get validationStatus$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._validationStatus.asObservable();
  }

  //plus more logic to update the observable
}

All this being said, it would be helpful to know what specific problem you're trying to solve without prompting a technical solution. What I've proposed sounds like it might be overkill for validating forms. What's the intended purpose of the directive?
